# Pull cell data from a table for use in a stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, pivot

I'm using a pivot command and I've got it producing the desired output as written below:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

SELECT      Id, IssuedCN, [EmailAddress], [ServerHostName], [ManagerEmail]

FROM        (SELECT Id, IssuedCN, StringValue, Name
         FROM dbo.certmetadata) AS Source

PIVOT(
MAX(StringValue)
FOR Name IN ([EmailAddress], [ServerHostName], [ManagerEmail])
)

AS PvtTable_1;
```

But the pivoted table names are going to be user defined. The current ones, [EmailAddress] [ServerHostName] [ManagerEmail], will probably stay there but could be changed or even non-existent. The user defined names are stored in a table but I can't seem to figure out how, if possible, to bring them into the above code.

I'm using server 2012.

If that doesn't make sense let me know and I can try to provide more detail.

Thanks!

Comment: There could also be anywhere from 0-12 different user defined columns.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are going to have an unknown number of columns, then you will need to look at using dynamic SQL.  The basic syntax will be similar to this:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

-- get the list of columns
-- apply a filter on the columns here if needed    
select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Name) 
                    from dbo.certmetadata
                    group by name
                    order by name
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT Id, IssuedCN,' + @cols + ' 
            from 
            (
                SELECT Id, IssuedCN, StringValue, Name
                from dbo.certmetadata
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                min(stringvalue)
                for name in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```